# Quais são os erros desse trecho de código em C que faz a soma dos nós de uma árvore binária?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

```
int somaFolha(struct NO **Raiz)
{
  int somaF;

  if (Raiz != NULL)
  {
    if (Raiz->esq == NULL || Raiz->dir == NULL)
      somaF += Raiz->valor;
    else
    {
      somaF = somaFolha((*Raiz).esq);
      somaF += somaFolha(Raiz->dir);
    }
  }

  return somaF;
}
```

Comment: No título está escrito "somar todos os nós de uma árvore binária", mas a função se chama `somaFolha`. O que você realmente deseja?

Answer (score 4):

No caso de `Raiz` ser `NULL`, você está retornando lixo, uma vez que nesse caso, `folhaF` não está sendo inicializado. Nesse caso é melhor retornar zero.

Também vejo que você está usando `||`, mas para verificar se o nó é folha, deveria ser `&&`.

Como o companheiro zentrunix percebeu, você também está usando `struct NO **` quando deveria ser apenas `struct NO *`.

Além disso, sugiro renomear `Raiz` para `raiz` e `somaFolha` para `soma_folha` de forma a ficar de acordo com o padrão do C.

E dá para simplificar bastante o código. Sugiro que ele fique assim:

```
int soma_folha(struct NO *raiz) {
     if (raiz == NULL) return 0;
     if (raiz->esq == NULL && raiz->dir == NULL) return raiz->valor;
     return soma_folha(raiz->esq) + soma_folha(raiz->dir);
}
```

Se você for fã do operador ternário, dá para simplificar um pouco mais:

```
int soma_folha(struct NO *raiz) {
     return raiz == NULL ? 0
             : raiz->esq == NULL && raiz->dir == NULL ? raiz->valor
             : soma_folha(raiz->esq) + soma_folha(raiz->dir);
}
```

Comment: aah Obrigado, O que não entendi também foi esse trecho:                                           
             somaF = somaFolha((*Raiz).esq);
             somaF += somaFolha(Raiz->dir);

Comment: @ElvesSousa A ideia é pegar o valor do `somaFolha` da subárvore esquerda, o valor da subárvor direita e somar os dois.

Comment: tem uma coisa estranha, acho que o parâmetro "struct NO ** raiz" deveria ser apenas "struct NO * raiz"...

Comment: @zentrunix É verdade. Muito obrigado pela observação.

Comment: Acho que vale mencionar que `folhaF` não foi inicializado e, portanto, pode retornar lixo de memória. Não que isso vá alterar o seu código final, mas o AP pediu para listar todos os erros, não foi?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Feito.